# Solving $\nabla f=g$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For $f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let $\nabla f=(\partial_{x_1}f,\ldots,\partial_{x_n}f)$ denote its gradient.
Under what conditions on $\boldsymbol{g}=(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$, the equation $\nabla f=\boldsymbol{g}$ admits a solution?

For $n=1$, this problem is simple and for any continuous function $g:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x):=\int_0^xf(s) d s$ does the job.

The case $n>1$, does not seem trivial to me. A precise necessary and sufficient conditon will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That partials commute implies a necessary condition, namely $\partial_ig_j = \partial_jg_i$ for all $1 \le i,j \le n$. On a cube or ball, this is also a sufficient condition and can be proved using the fundamental theorem of calculus. On a cube $[0,1]^n$, the easiest way is by induction on the dimension. The idea is to assume there is a solution on the $(n-1)$-cube given by $x^n = 0$ and then extend it to a possible solution on the full curve using the fundamental theorem of calculus along each vertical line segment $t -> (x^1, \dots, x^{n-1},t)$, $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: It is not trivial whatsoever. In fact your question is the focus of a significant fraction of an entire graduate course in differential topology.

Comment: @LeeMosher Could you please suggest a reference

Comment: The key word is differential forms. There are various books at the graduate student level. There's an entry level book by Spivak entitled *Calculus on Manifolds*. At an advanced level there's a book by Bott and Tu entitled *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: @Deane Could you please elaborate it a bit with  some details of the computation

Comment: One way is to use a line integral. The proof is essentially the same as the 1d case. Assume $\Omega$ is connected and simply connected. Pick any $x_0\in\Omega$. For any other $x\in\Omega$, let $c: [0,1]\rightarrow\Omega$ be a smooth curve from $x_0$ to $x$. Let $$f(x) = \int_0^1 c’(t)\cdot g(c(t))\,dt.$$ If, for any $1\le i,j\le n$, $$\partial_ig_j=\partial_jg_i,$$ Stokes’ Theorem and the assumption that $\Omega$ is simply connected imply that the value of $f(x)$ as defined above is independent of the curve used. It is now straightforward to show $\nabla f=g$.